# Error when exporting printers and drivers from Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, printing, drivers

I'm trying to copy the printers and drivers from a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine to another server. I went to the Print Management console and right clicked on Print Management, then clicked on Migrate Printers and exported the printers and drivers to a file and saved it on my desktop. Once the export was completed, I was given the following error:

```
Printbrm.exe (the Printer Migration Wizard or the command-line tool) failed to backup port WSD-xxxxxx. The backup process will continue, skipping this port. Error: 0x80070057. The parameter is incorrect.
```

I looked into the WSD port and it appears that it ["makes devices Plug and Play through a network rather than requiring a USB cable."](https://www.urtech.ca/2013/09/solved-what-is-the-difference-between-a-tcpip-printer-port-and-a-wsd-printer-port/) Will there be any issues on my new server if the port isn't backed up and I import the file on the new server? If so, is there a way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I really doubt, that you are using any WSD (Web Services on Devices) in your environment. Check in Print Management Console, if any of printers uses WSD port. If not – then, you’ll not have any issues on the new server.